If a Banach manifold satisfies the Heine-Borel property, then does it have finite dimension?
Suppose $C$ is a topological Banach manifold, that is also a closed convex subset of a Banach space $E$, also, $C$ satisfies the Heine-Borel property:

Every closed and bounded (with respect to the norm of $E$) subset of $C$ is compact.

Is is true that $C$ is a finite dimensional topological manifold? (I'm working with a closed convex subset, but I don't think this condition is necessary)
I tried showing that the Banach space to which $C$ is locally homeomorphic must satisfy the Heine-Borel property (and therefore it is finite dimensional), but I'm not quite sure if it is correct. My thought is that I could take a chart that every preimage of closed and bounded subset would be a closed bounded subset and therefore compact, so the image is also compact, but I'm not quite sure if the charts will satisfy this. Is my idea correct? If so, could you explain me why the charts satisfy this property?

"Chart" maps an open of $C$ onto an open in some Banach space or the other way round? (This info is needed to understand your remark on preimages)

Do you know the definition of a Banach manifold?

My suggestion is to spell out exactly what definition of a Banach manifold you are using.

Depending on your definition of "manifold", the Hilbert cube may be a counterexample. The Hilbert cube is the subset of $\ell^2$ consisting of those sequences $(x_n)$ satisfying $0\le x_n \le 1/n$. It is homeomorphic to the infinite product
$$
[0, 1]\times [0, 1/2]\times [0, 1/3]\times\ldots, $$
so it is compact by Tychonoff's theorem, but it does not seem "finite dimensional" to me.
Remark. The Hilbert cube is closed and convex, which seems to match the "definition" of Banach manifold you gave in the question. If this is really what you are looking for, then the Hilbert cube is a counterexample. Usually a "Banach manifold" is something different, though. I am not an expert on that, but still, the existence of the Hilbert cube seems to hint at a negative answer to your question, however you make it precise.
Remark 2. After a bit of discussion in comments, it seems that this is not a counterexample. The Hilbert cube is closed and convex, but it is not a Banach manifold according to the usual definition (which is still missing from the question), as Moishe Cohen explains.

It has infinite covering dimension.

@MoisheKohan: Yes. There clearly is a problem with definitions in this question (see my edit). In any case, my intuition is that the answer should be negative, provided the question is posed correctly.

And, yet, with the standard definition of  a Banach manifold, the answer to the title  question is positive. Sigh... Just for the record, manifolds modeled on the Hilbert tube are quite interesting, they are sometimes called Q-manifolds. But they are not Banach manifolds with the standard definition.

I think that I wasn't clear at what I said, I'm not saying a Banach manifold is a closed and convex subset, but that the manifold I was considering is also a closed and convex subset
